# derive ngrams that have independent meaning to feed into visualization part

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram, part-of-speech

Having some customer reviews, I derived important themes in the corpus[cost, side effect, time to take effect].
Now for each theme, I want to do sentiment analysis in this way:
derive n grams that have independent meaning and are related to the theme. For instance as you see, in the picture there are 3 themes. in the theme "time to take effect",phrases like "a while" or "not immediate" are related ngrams.

What I've done in Python: for each theme I manually, divided the corpus into 2 strata,

1. sentences with the words related to theme
2. sentences with no word related to the theme

Then for each word, I calculated the overindexing with the hope that the words that we want to be overindexed in the sentence. (eg. ['It', 0.001] ['is', 0.001], ['n't', 0.002], ['immediate', 0.042], ['but', 0.002], ['it', 0.001], ['does',0.002], ['work', 0.002])
but this didn't work because some other words unrelated to the theme have very high overindexing values.

Is there any other option that I could derive n-grams related to the theme?
my final goal is to produce something like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems similar to collocations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation), except you're looking for ngrams rather than general bigrams. Maybe try modifying the approach on that page, where you look for sequences that appear more often than chance